# ValueError when trying to use more than 3 values in input

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, if I wanna accept to inputs from a user seperated by a space, I'd use this code:

```
x, _, x2 = input("> ").lower().partition(' ')
```

Which works fine. However, if I wanna accept 3 responses, then I'd get a ValueError:

```
x, _, x2, _, x3 = input("> ").lower().partition(' ')
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 3)
```

So, how can I accept more than two "inputs" using this (or another) method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `partition` method always returns only 3 values:

```
S.partition(sep) -> (head, sep, tail)

Search for the separator sep in S, and return the part before it,
the separator itself, and the part after it.  If the separator is not
found, return S and two empty strings.
```

You probably want `split`.

```
x1, x2, x2 = input("> ").lower().split(' ')
```

Or more flexibly:

```
xs = input("> ").lower().split(' ')
```

Or in one shot:

```
x1, x2, x3 = (input("> ").lower().split(' ') + [None, None, None])[0:3]
```

Comment: That works, but I'm wanting to allow people to enter less than 3 as well, so they could do something like "foo" or "foo bar" instead of having to always write three things. (for a command like "copy" which needs 3 "answers", but with something like "rename" only needs 2)

Comment: @Brendan Then assign to a list or use the 3rd approach above.